# Bean not properly injected into another bean when using Wicket stateless page

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, wicket

I have a problem with `wicket-spring-boot` <-> `wicket` integration. Bean annotated with `@Service` is not properly injected into a backing bean that is injected into a stateless Page using `@SpringBean` annotation.

Generally:

```
@StatelessComponent
@MountPath("home-page")
public class HomePage extends WebPage {

    @SpringBean
    private HomePageHandler handler;
}
```

and

```
@Service
public class HomePageHandler {

    private final CommandPublisher commandPublisher;

    @Autowired
    public HomePageHandler(CommandPublisher commandPublisher) {
        this.commandPublisher = commandPublisher;
    }

    public void executeAction(String name) {
        commandPublisher.publish(name); /// <----------- NPE (commandPublisher is null)
    }
}
```

and:

```
@Service
public class CommandPublisher {

    public void publish(String text) {
        eventPublisher.publishEvent(text);
    }

}
```

Wicket 7.6.0, wicket-spring-boot 1.0.6.

I have created a simple starter (https://github.com/tdziurko/wicket-spring-bean-issue) to reproduce the problem. Problem disappears when page is not stateless (more info in readme in the starter).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is related to using concrete classes instead of interfaces with which CGLIB has problems. Switching to using an interface or using Objenesis should solve the problem.

I have answered this question in detail at the mailing lists (http://markmail.org/message/xggw6ajuxz22rllh) and at Wicket-Spring-Boot issues (https://github.com/MarcGiffing/wicket-spring-boot/issues/98#issuecomment-291606918).

No hard feelings but such cross posts in all possible forums waste time to many people.
Let's focus on one forum!

Comment: @Martin-g: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers

Comment: @Kukeltje can't you read ?! Even the OP agreed that asking the same question in N forums is not the best way to spend our time. Feel free to remove both my answer and the question. And to find better things to do instead of bothering us!

Comment: I can read perfectly (in Dutch, German, French, English and even a little Spanish) And I also agree that duplicate posts are not good but neither are link-only answers in Stackoverflow. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer (the 'Provide context' part), not providing a fully duplicate answer (that is not stated anywhere)